# Erro ao executar npm start

Tags: node.js, npm

Fiz a instalação do Node.js seguindo as instruções do site da ionic, a instalação ocorreu normalmente porém quando tento dar o comando "npm start" pego esse erro, ele me fala que o npm não está achando um diretório ou um arquivo, e da uns erros na pasta package.json... não sei como resolver isso galera, segue o passo a passo e os erros que peguei:

> ```
> MacBook-Pro-de-Lucas:~ lucas$ npm start
>
> npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
>
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.11.0
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>
> npm ERR! path /Users/lucas/package.json
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno -2
>
> npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
> '/Users/lucas/package.json'
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/lucas/package.json'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> npm ERR! enoent 
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/lucas/npm-debug.log
>
> MacBook-Pro-de-Lucas:~ lucas$
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que o problema é que você está tentando dar um `npm start` na sua home.

Ao rodar um `npm start`, o npm tenta encontrar um arquivo package.json, com a definição do que o start deveria fazer.
O que você provavelmente quer é rodar esse comando dentro da pasta raiz de algum projeto que contenha um `package.json`.

Answer (score -2):

Se voce chegou neste topico muito provavelmente esta iniciando em React Node JS, e muito provavelmente nao viu que no CMD/TERMINAL vc nao esta dentro da pasta do projeto que criou com o comando (npx create-react-app NOMEDOPROJETO), entao entre na pasta com o comando 'CD DIRETORIO DA PASTA DO PROJETO' e entao execute o comando (npm start).
Veja que tudo que ele fez foi nao reconhecer um arquivo que nao estava dentro do diretorio que voce estava no momento que mandou executar a instalacao desses arquivos anteriormente criado.

Answer (score -2):

Verifique se o package.json do seu projeto está correto! No meu, o package.json estava falatando o:
"scripts": {
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1",
"start": "lite-server"
},
O lite-server, eu instalei usando o comando npm install lite-server
package.json completo:
{
"scripts": {
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1",
"start": "lite-server"
},
"dependencies": {
"lite-server": "^2.6.1",
"npm": "^8.16.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"typescript": "^4.7.4"
}
}